# How to check in a workflow 2010 condition if an element is exist or not?

Tags: workflow, custom-list, conditional

The users can create items in a custom list. One element of the item is the "date of warning". If the user add a date he/she ll recive an e-mail on that date if the "status" is not "finished" yet. The "date of warning" is not a field the user must add, so sometimes it is empty. I would like to check if the field is empty or not, and abort the workflow or not even start if it is empty. (I use 2010 workflows)

Thank you very much for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the below steps:

1. Create a local workflow variable of type string, say `dateAsString`.
2. Use command `Set workflow variable`. In `variable` select the newly create i.e. `dateAsString`. In value select `fx` in the open dialog box select `Current Item, FieldName, and Short Date`.
3. Now write if statement and check if workflow variable is equals `1/1/0001`.

[image]
This will solve your problem.

**Explanation**

SharePoint stores every data into SQL and in SQL the empty date is equals .NET MinimumDate object which is actually `01/01/0001 12:00 AM`. So we are converting empty date into string and checking if its equals mini date string or not.

Comment: welcome dear :)